# How do I omit 1 value from string union type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

I have type:

```js
type someType = 'type1' | 'type2' | 'type3' | 'type4';
```

How do I omit one of the values?

For instance I want something like this:

```js
type newType = Omit<someType, 'type2'> // newType = 'type1' | 'type3' | 'type4'
```

Comment: You already `omit` it what are you looking for exactly?

Comment: `Omit` doesn't work with literals - it omits **keys**. `type Narrow<T extends SomeType = SomeType> = T extends 'type2' ? never : T;` should do the trick.

Comment: @Joseph it's not working or i'm doing something wrong: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAzg9gWwgFXNAvFA5KSBGLKAH21wgCZCSc0BmK0tAFiwG4AodsqAOwgHdUkKJgDyCAJbAAPPCRCIAGkaRKAPigB6TbwEKRKiAWKH6JmpBacAxnB4xgu-qIBGAKwBcT-ZgsQWrEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludeuniontype-excludedmembers) utility type (instead of `Omit`, which operates on *keys* of an interface):

> `Exclude<UnionType, ExcludedMembers>`
>
> Constructs a type by excluding from `UnionType` all union members that are assignable to `ExcludedMembers`.

In your case:

```
type someType = 'type1' | 'type2' | 'type3' | 'type4';

type newType = Exclude<someType, 'type2'>
//   ^? "type1" | "type3" | "type4"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAzg9gWwgFXNAvFA5KSBGLKAH21wgCZCSc0BmK0tAFiwG4AodsqAOwgHdUkKJgCiADwDGAGwCuAEwgAeeEiEQANI0iUAfFAD0B3gPUjtEAsQv1rNSC3ZGoLgHoB+dkA)